# How ltrim(s,t), rtrim(s,t) in Netezza SQL Convert to Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, hive, trim, netezza

Can anyone tell me what are the equivalent Netezza SQL functions for ltrim(s,t) and rtrim(s,t) in Hive SQL? I really appreciate it!

I know in Netezza SQL,

Select ltrim('abcd','a');

> 'bcd'

Select rtrim('abcd','d');

> 'abc'

But what about

Select ltrim('aaaabaabcd','a');

Select rtrim('abcdbddddd','d');?

And what are the equivalent functions for ltrim() and rtrim() in Hive SQL?

Comment: You say "what about ...", but what do you actually get (in both languages) ? and what do you expect to get ?

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

In Hive it can be done using regexp_replace.

Trimming left:

```
select regexp_replace('aaaabaabcd','^a*','');
OK
baabcd
```

Trimming right:

```
select regexp_replace('aaaabaabcda','a*$','');
OK
aaaabaabcd
```

Trimming left and right:

```
select regexp_replace('aaaabaabcda','^(a*)|(a*)$','');
OK
baabcd
```

Trimming combination of chars at the end of the string:

```
select regexp_replace('aaaabaabcdabcda','(bcda)*$','');
OK
aaaabaa
```

Regexp is powerful and you can do much more complex transformations also using regexp_extract function. See [functions manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions).